# What is the correct port answer for SFTP - 115 or 22?

Tags: sftp

CompTIA's Network+ CertMaster Learn content agrees with Wikipedia that some use port TCP port 22 for SFTP or FTP over SSH (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol).
But IANA's RFC6335 states differently:

TCP/UDP port 115 is the Simple File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)
https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=115

TCP/UDP port 22 is the Secure Shell Protocol (SSH)
https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=22

I submitted the question to CompTIA but haven't hear back from them yet.

Answer (score 2):

- SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not FTP over SSH. It is a different protocol to FTP.
- SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is not SFTP (Simple File Transfer Protocol). They are different protocols.
- SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is intended to be tunnelled over a secure channel, most commonly SSH. The correct port for SSH is 22.